# ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes django

Tags: python, django

Whenever I try to run the server these error is popping up. Yesterday it was working fine. Tried for a long but don't get any solution for that.

Comment: maybe you can add the terminal output

Comment: Instead of all the fluff, add all the details needed to solve this.